# What is "==+!" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone can show me what is "==+!" meaning in below code:

```
if(my_var.length==+!0) //do something
```

I try google but don't get the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it like this:

```
if (my_var.length == (+(!0)))
```

Since `!0 === true` and `+true === 1`, you end up with this sequence of evaluation:

```
if (my_var.length == (+(!0)))
if (my_var.length == (+true))
if (my_var.length == 1)
```

FYI, you can see an ordered list of Javascript operator precedence when deciding how to process operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Of relevance here, the precendence of the `!` operator is highest, then the `unary +` operator and then the `==` operator.

See the results of `!0` and `+true` here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wh840n3q/

Answer (score 0):

That's just:

```
if(my_var.length==1)
```

Because `!0` is `true` and `+true` is `1` :)

Comment: `!0` === `true`, not `1`.